# What is the rigorous description of scattering in relativistic QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, scattering

The first conundrum is what picture of QM to choose, in order to describe such a scattering. Unlike in non-relativistic QM, in  RQFT the three all-known pictures are not at all equivalent. The Schrodinger picture is more or less meaningless since the Schrodinger equation is not relativistic invariant (since it contains only a time derivative, whereas a general Lorentz transformation mixes time and space coordinates). Moreover, the very notion of a state vector defined at a finite time, $|\psi(t)\rangle$, is very problematic in RQFT for many reasons. Dirac has a very interesting paper ("Quantum Electrodynamics without dead wood" published in Phys. Rev., http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.139.B684) in which he shows that.
    The interaction picture does not exist in RQFT due to Haag's theorem.
    One is left with only the Heisenberg picture. I haven't encountered a serious treatment of scattering in the Heisenberg picture anywhere, not even in non-relativistic QM, let alone in RQFT. I would be very much interested in such a setting, namely in how to describe the state vectors at the beginning and at the end of scattering, the operators, the time evolution, and above all, how to make everything relativistically invariant. If somebody could write a book or lecture notes on such an important topic it would be a match made in heaven.
    Usually, the books on RQFT, and I think I consulted most of them (at least all that are in my university's library), treat the scattering problem very non-rigorously (even the treatise by Weinberg), giving a lot of hand-waving arguments in which they use at least a forbidden step, the treatment is not fully relativistic from beginning to end, etc., just to arrive at the Feynman diagrams.
    I've recently heard about a way to circumvent the interaction picture by using the Haag-Ruelle scattering theory. I don't know much about it since it is very technical and mathematically demanding, but my question is this: is this treatment fully and manifestly relativistic from the beginning to the end?

Comment: There is a book "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory" of lectures given by Dirac at the Belfer Graduate School of Science, Yeshiva University, New York in 1963-64 which says similar things to the paper cited in the question. On page 148, Dirac says, "I just do not know how to define an S-matrix working with the Heisenberg picture.  ... the usual way of introducing it in field theory involves so much departure from logic that I do not see how one could take it over into a logical theory."

Comment: @StephenBlake, that's an interesting comment. Do you know if the book is online somewhere?

Comment: @Jan Lalinsky : I cannot find Dirac's lectures online. It's possible to get a copy at Abebooks http://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=14278217882&searchurl=sts%3Dt%26sortby%3D20%26tn%3DLectures+on+quantum+field+theory%26an%3DDirac

Comment: @StephenBlake Dirac was wrong! I've discovered that H. Ekstein did just that, presenting the most lucid treatment of scattering theory in the Heisenberg picture in [Scattering in field theory](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02745471). It's a superb paper!

Comment: @AndreaBecker  I've just begun to study H. Ekstein's paper and have an initial worry. Suppose the system is in state $|\psi_{H}\rangle$ in the Heisenberg picture. We are interested in measuring the observable $\hat{A}_{S}$

Comment: @StephenBlake See my description of scattering that I've gathered from Ekstein's paper [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274564/why-is-there-a-time-dependence-in-the-heisenberg-states-of-the-haag-ruelle-scatt). If you still have questions please ask.

Comment: @StephenBlake All description is entirely in the Heisenberg picture! Both operators and state vectors! Schrodinger picture just doesn't exist in qft due to vacuum polarization effects (see EDIT 2 [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210345/how-to-describe-time-evolution-in-relativistic-qft)). See also my last comments there about your -1 :)

Comment: @AndreaBecker I could not write quickly enough to ask my question about Ekstein's paper in a comment, perhaps I should start a new question with the title "Scattering theory in the Heisenberg picture". What do you think?

Comment: @StephenBlake What I meant by "Dirac was wrong!" does not refer to his comments about the Schrodinger picture, but to his statement quoted by you as to not being possible to introduce an S-matrix while working entirely within the Heisenberg picture!

Comment: @StephenBlake Of course, if you want, you could start a question. Just send me a link to it.

Comment: @AndreaBecker I understand that you are saying that Ekstein has an S matrix in the Heisenberg picture. My worry about Ekstein's paper is that the eigenstates of the operator at the final time are formally given by a unitary operator acting on the eigenstates at the initial time and the unitary operator does not exist so the initial and final eigenstates are in inequivalent subspaces and the scattering matrix does not exist.

Comment: @StephenBlake No, your worry is unfounded. An operator is defined by its matrix in a given basis and not between 2 bases. <a,+|S|b,+>=<a,+|b,->. Of course, any 2 bases in a Hilbert space are related by a unitary transformation, but I don't see any problem. Try to write an equation. Be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Scattering in relativistic QFT is rigorously treated in Haag-Ruelle theory, which is based on the Heisenberg picture. See

K. Hepp, On the connection between the LSZ and Wightman quantum field theory, Comm. Math. Phys. 1 (1965), 95-111. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103758732